# What is the tensorial representation of the quantum swap gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, linear-algebra

I need to write the tensorial representation of the Controlled Swap Gate, what I have written is 
$\operatorname{CSWAP}=|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I\otimes I+|1\rangle\langle1|\otimes U$, where U is the matrix of $\operatorname{CSWAP}$ gate transformation, i.ethat is $$|00\rangle\to |00\rangle=1|00\rangle+0|01\rangle+0|10\rangle +0|11\rangle $$
$$ |01\rangle=0|00\rangle+0|01\rangle+1|10\rangle +0|11\rangle $$
$$|10\rangle=0|00\rangle+1|01\rangle+0|10\rangle +0|11\rangle $$
$$|11\rangle=0|00\rangle+0|01\rangle+0|10\rangle +1|11\rangle,$$ so the matrix becomes $$U=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix},$$
Is this the correct implementation? Just to add a bit, how do I make this $2$-qubit gate as a tensor product of $1$-qubit gate so that there is uniformity in the equation above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWAP is a two-qubit gate and needs to be written as
$$
\text{SWAP}=|00\rangle\langle 00|+|11\rangle\langle 11|+|01\rangle\langle 10|+|10\rangle\langle 01|.
$$
If you want to write this in terms of Pauli-operators, for example, you might write
$$
\text{SWAP}=\frac12\left(\mathbb{I}\otimes\mathbb{I}+Z\otimes Z+X\otimes X+Y\otimes Y\right).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the correct matrix representation of the CSWAP (also often referred to as [Fredkin gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredkin_gate)).

Regarding writing it as a "*tensor product of $1$-qubit gates*", the only missing step is writing the swap in braket notation, which you can do as follows:
$$\operatorname{SWAP}=\lvert00\rangle\!\langle00\rvert+\lvert11\rangle\!\langle11\rvert+\lvert01\rangle\!\langle10\rvert+\lvert10\rangle\!\langle01\rvert,$$
so that the overall gate reads
\begin{align}
\operatorname{CSWAP}&=|0\rangle\!\langle0|\otimes I\otimes I+|1\rangle\!\langle1|\otimes \operatorname{SWAP}\\
&=|0\rangle\!\langle0|\otimes I\otimes I+|1\rangle\!\langle1|\otimes(\lvert00\rangle\!\langle00\rvert+\lvert11\rangle\!\langle11\rvert+\lvert01\rangle\!\langle10\rvert+\lvert10\rangle\!\langle01\rvert).
\end{align}

Comment: okay, that is what i was missing.

Comment: I think your "tensor product of $1$-qubit gates" representation is incorrect. As this representation will give a simple $X$-gate, not a $\text{SWAP}$-gate

Comment: @nippon it most definitely is, yes. I probably wasn't quite awake yet. Thanks